# How add click event div runat server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I having difficulty in meeting add an event click on a div tag with runat = "server".
This works perfectly on IE but not on chrome, mozilla .. Search error :-)

Here is the code I tried

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function showAlertAnomalie() {
   alert("Handler test");
}
```

**ASP:**

```
<div id="btn_alert_anomalie" class="alertAnomalieClass" runat="server"  onclick="showAlertAnomalie" >
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Alert annomaly" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12" ForeColor="White" style="cursor:pointer;"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

**I ave also try this but not work.. :**

```
$("#btn_alert_anomalie").click(function () {
   alert("Handler test");
});
```

Comment: try onclick="showAlertAnomalie();"

Comment: It will generate a new id for the div while you add `runat="server"`. So $('#btn_alert_anomalie') can't find the exactly div what your want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inline `onclick` attribute is supposed to contain the *body* of the click handler, not the name of it. Try this:

```
onclick="showAlertAnomalie();"
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/UgcEQ/

The problem was that doing this:

```
onclick="showAlertAnomalie"
```

is equivalent to doing this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn_alert_anomalie');
btn.onclick = function(){
    showAlertAnomalie
}
```

which doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 2):

try with `class` of `div` as

```
$(".alertAnomalieClass").click(function () {
   alert("Handler test");
});
```

here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yRBbB/)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('#<%=btn_alert_anomalie.ClientID%>').click(function () {
 alert("Handler test");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't matter... Happy to be Helpful..:)